# NerdDinner ASP Tutorial - Linq-to-Sql does not create collection for OneToMany

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nerddinner

I'm trying to follow the ASP.NET Nerd Dinner tutorial of Microsoft, but I'm having problems with the linq-to-sql part.

I have the two databases Dinner and RSVP with primary keys and identity set to `DinnerID` and `RsvpID`. Then I created the relation `FK_RSVP_Dinner` with foreign key `RSVP.DinnerID` and pk `Dinner.DinnerID`

When creating the LinqToSql class and drag the two tables in, it creates the OneToMany relation successfully.

[image: LinqToSql Class]
However, the NerdDinner.designer.cs file does not contain any collection called RSVPs, but only a variable RSVP.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things to check:

Look in the NerdDinner.dbml's designer.cs file under the RSVP partial class definition and the Dinner partial class definition:

public partial class RSVP....

1. Make sure RsvpID is an Identity type of Primary Key with auto-generation of the key.

[Column(Storage="_RsvpID", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]

1. A private EntityRef type should have been generated:

private EntityRef _Dinner;

1. Check the association property:
   [Association(Name="Dinner_RSVP", Storage="_Dinner", ThisKey="DinnerID", OtherKey="DinnerID", IsForeignKey=true)]
   public Dinner Dinner......

Do the same for the Dinner partial class...

1. Is the primary key correctly defined?
2. Is a EntitySet _Rsvps defined?
3. Is there and association defined:
   [Association(Name="Dinner_RSVP", Storage="_RSVPs", ThisKey="DinnerID", OtherKey="DinnerID")]
   public EntitySet RSVPs....

Hope that helps...